# Selenium C# - Unable to click on element with xlink:href attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to Selenium for C#. I want to click on the element between the `<svg>` tag (image below). I have tried the following :

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//use[@href='#events-widget']")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//use[@href='#events-widget'/]")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//use[@xlink:href='#events-widget']")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//use[@xlink:href='#events-widget']/")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Events")).Click();
```

[image]

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the FindElement returning an IWebElement?

Comment: Yes it returns an IWebElement

Comment: Sometimes you got to click twice because the first time only focus the control. In other words, you have to repeat the line twice.

Comment: @Fjodr Hi ! I will try that :). But are any of these calls correct ?

Comment: Not sure I have not used xPath. I prefer by.Id.

Comment: you can test the xpath in the console of the browser's developer tools by entering $x("//use[@href='#events-widget']")

Comment: Can you please provide the html not the image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Selenium from C#, but from [Nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org/). We're using `<svg>` for icons and I select the `<use xlink:href="/svg-icons/sprite.stack.svg#sort-ascending"></use>` element with this css selector:

'use[*|href="/svg-icons/sprite.stack.svg#sort-ascending"]'

I would guess this also works from C#.