# click on element xlink:href in selnume webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have to click on an image in my website but I cannot find something that helps me to identify the image.

This  the code in the site:

```
<image fill-opacity="0" stroke="none" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" x="166" y="438" width="54" height="44" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://maps.b144.co.il/images_v2/map_route/b1.png " transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)"></image>
```

I tried to enter the herf to xpath like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//image/[@xlink:href= 'http://maps.b144.co.il/images_v2/map_route/b1.png']" )).click();
```

But this does not work, I'd love some help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error? `NoSuchElement` exception?

Answer (score 1):

As I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703738/selenium-c-sharp-unable-to-click-on-element-with-xlinkhref-attribute/30161109#30161109), you could try this css selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("image[*|href='http://maps.b144.co.il/images_v2/map_route/b1.png']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following locator:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("image[href='http://maps.b144.co.il/images_v2/map_route/b1.png']")).click();
```

Also, if this doesn't work, you can paste larger piece of the HTML so that I can give you another relative XPath expression to some element that has ID.

Comment: Thanks
But it has not worked. Here is an excerpt larger.
Thanks

<svg width="6" height="5" id="dvMap_gc" style="overflow: visible; position: absolute;">
<defs></defs>
<g id="dvMap_graphics_layer" transform="matrix(1.0)" style="display: block;">
<image fill-opacity="0" stroke="none" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" x="343" y="2" width="4" height="4" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/19/xlink" xlink:href="http://maps.b144.co.il/images_v2/map_route/b1.png " transform="matrix(1.0)">">
</image></g></svg>

Comment: Can you try this- //svg[@id="dvMap_gc"]/g[1] as XPath locator. If it doesn't work, it is possible the element to be located in a frame which means that you should first switch to the frame in order to work with its elements.

Answer (score 0):

From your Html, I see you have x and y co-ordinates.

you can use like this.

int  x=166;

int y=438;

and then call the robot api.

Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.mousemove(x,y);

Else you can try with imagelink. Refer the Link below for more ways.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html